# Postgres SUM help (not like expected)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, odoo

I would like to SUM balance with the fallowing query

```
SELECT account_id,partner_id,invoice_id,journal_id,
SUM(account_move_line.balance)
FROM public.account_move_line
WHERE (account_move_line.date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-31')
GROUP BY journal_id,account_id,partner_id,invoice_id,account_move_line.id ORDER BY account_move_line.id;
```

The result expected is the sum of balance for same account_id,invoice_id and journal_id in the result I expected the SUM of -62.63 and -34.43 but in fact not !

[capture table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp97g.png)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the column `account_move_line.id` from `GROUP BY` because what you want is to sum the balance for each combination of `account_id`, `partner_id`, `invoice_id` and `journal_id`:

```
SELECT 
  account_id,partner_id,invoice_id,journal_id,
  SUM(balance) total_balance
FROM public.account_move_line
WHERE (date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-31')
GROUP BY account_id,partner_id,invoice_id,journal_id 
ORDER BY account_id;
```

Comment: Thank it's running well, but same problem with that one

Comment: What do you mean same problem? This should return the SUM that you expect.

Comment: Thanks running well, I have the same problem with anoter query posted, can you help me ?

Comment: Added in the same post, you prefer that I create a new one ?

Comment: Ok I'll do it when possible, in 90' not allowed before.